# How to build mach-0 for different architectures?

Tags: macos, gcc, lame

I have some dylibs to load from python with ctypes.  I can load libbass.dylib without problem,  but I can't load the self-compiled libmp3lame.dylib.  Here is the error I get.

> OSError: dlopen(libmp3lame.dylib, 6):
>   no suitable image found.  Did find:
>    libmp3lame.dylib: mach-o, but wrong
>   architecture

Then, I inspect the file type of those libs. Here is the result of libbass.dylib:

```
libbass.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
libbass.dylib (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
libbass.dylib (for architecture ppc): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
```

And here is the self-compiled one:

```
libmp3lame.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I did compile the lame library with the install instructions:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I'm new to mac system, here comes the problem: how to build the libmp3lame.dylib so that it supports different architecture I want?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build march-0 for different architectures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981118/how-to-build-march-0-for-different-architectures)

Comment: Sorry, I have already the duplicate one.

Comment: reverted to your original post (actually, this one was the duplicate) but Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run:

```
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch pcc" ./configure
```

For further information, see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2005/tn2137.html